# Why I am not seeing all properties available in local.settings.json file after deploying Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created an Azure function using Visual Studio. `Local.setting.json` file had following properties:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusConnString": "Endpoint=sb://sb-new-two.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=9FygKPHH2eJVp3GmAiUxtT7sGnddsaddadNIrciM0=",
    "Test": "sb-new-two.servicebus.windows.net"
  }
}
```

This is how my function looks:

```
   [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic-one", "sub-one", Connection = "ServiceBusConnString")] string mySbMsg)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Processing message");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Message : {mySbMsg}");
        Console.WriteLine(mySbMsg);
    }
```

After deploying the azure function, I do not see the test property. I am not using it in my code. But wondering why is this property missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `.gitignore` file if it includes the `local.settings.json`. Better yet add the value of your Test config manually in the Configuration section of your Azure function. Go to your function app in Azure, under Settings > Configuration > New Application setting, then add your Test config.

Answer (score 0):

**One of the workarounds to publish the app settings from `local.settings.json` to the Azure Portal Function App Configuration is**:

Before publishing the function project to the Azure Portal, below is the configuration of my Function App:

[image]

**Azure Functions Core Tools cmdlet**:

```
func azure functionapp publish KrishSbFunApp01 --publish-local-settings -i
```

[image]

[image]

Before running this cmdlet, you have to change the value of `AzureWebJobsStorage` to the Azure Storage account connection string.

Also, you can overwrite the app settings by using the parameter `--overwrite-settings -y`, available in [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish) Source.